# Select top 2 from distinct fields with another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table as such:

```
PointOfSaleId, Name, Address
```

I would like to Select the top 2 records having the same `Name` and `Address`, together with the `PointOfSaleId`.

For instance I got the following records:

```
PointOfSaleId Name  Address
1             Foo   Bar
2             Foo   Bar
3             Foo   Bar
4             Foo2  Bar2
```

the result should select the following:

```
1             Foo   Bar
2             Foo   Bar
4             Foo2  Bar2
```

Is there any feasible way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [row_number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function and write query like:

```
select 
    T.PointOfSaleId,
    T.Name,
    T.Address
from
(
    select
        PointOfSaleId,
        Name,
        Address,
        row_number() over (partition by Name, Address order by PointOfSaleId asc) as Num
   from your_Table
) as T
where T.Num <= 2
```

This will enumerate all pairs of same `Name` and `Address` ordered by `PointOfSaleId` in the inner query, and then in outer query you're selecting only top two of each pairs.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select top(2) with ties PointOfSaleId, Name, Address
from myTable
order by row_number() over (partition by Name, Address order by PointOfSaleId)
```